# SAS EG export to different test folder conditional statement

Tags: sas

My code exports a table from SAS to a excel file in a folder.
My goal to change the export folder to a test folder if I set the variable test to 1.
This is my code:

```
/*Delete .bak files*/
%macro xlsx_bak_delete(file, file_name) / des='Delete backup spreadsheets';
option mprint notes;
data _null_;
fname = 'todelete';
rc = filename(fname, "&file.&file_name..xlsx.bak");
rc = fdelete(fname);
rc = filename(fname);
run;
%mend xlsx_bak_delete;

/*Export*/
%macro ExportExcel(path,file_name,table_name);
proc export data=&table_name
    outfile="&path.&file_name..xlsx"
    dbms=xlsx
    replace;
    ;
run;
%xlsx_bak_delete(&export_path, &file_name)
%mend;

%LET test = 1

%IF test = 1 %then %do;
    /*TEST export path */
    %Let export_path = \\Bfd1\b00369\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Daglig LCR - Axiom\Test\;
%end;
%else %do;
    /*Export path*/
    %Let export_path = \\Bfd1\b00369\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Daglig LCR - Axiom\Test_prod\;
%end;

/*Datetiemstamp macro*/
%let fileTimeStamp = %sysfunc(date(), ddmmyyd10.)_%sysfunc(putc(%sysfunc(time(), b8601TM6.), $6.)) ;
%put &fileTimeStamp.;


%ExportExcel(&export_path,DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER_&fileTimeStamp.,QUERY_FOR_DAGLIGEKORREKTIONER);
```

The issue is that my code only exports to the test_prod folder nothing changes if test is = 0 or 1 why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly referencing the [macro variable](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/macro/z1071889.htm#:%7E:text=After%20a%20macro%20variable%20is,anywhere%20in%20a%20SAS%20program.). As a result, it will always end up in the `%else %do;` part of the `%if` statement.
You can use the variable by referencing it with an ampersand preceding its name (`&test` in your case), which is called a macro variable reference.

You are also missing a semicolon `;` after the `%LET` statement.

```
%LET test = 1;

%IF &test = 1 %then %do;
    /*TEST export path */
    %Let export_path = \\Bfd1\b00369\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Daglig LCR - Axiom\Test\;
%end;
%else %do;
    /*Export path*/
    %Let export_path = \\Bfd1\b00369\Afdeling\HS-OKO\Oko\Likviditet\Likviditetsstyring\LCR\Daglig LCR - Axiom\Test_prod\;
%end;
```